# Extract sub string between two string with new line

Tags: c#, regex

Please help me to write a regular expression to extract the entire content between * .
Note the number of * characters can vary.

I tried `(\*\n)([\s\S]*)(\n\*)` but it groups everything as 1 block instead of 2.

**Expected Output**

1.

```
Thanks for contacting us    
Regards,    
XXX
```

2.

```
It wAS  a pleasure talking with you
Good to see you today
```

**Test string:**

```
*******

Thanks for contacting us    
Regards,    
XXX

************

It wAS  a pleasure talking with you    
Good to see you today

*******
```

Comment: `Regex.Matches(s, @"(?s)\*{3,}(.*?)(?=\*{3,}|$)").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value.Trim()).ToList()`

Comment: it only matches the first group

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?s)\*{3,}(.*?)(?=\*{3,}|$)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value.Trim())
    .ToList();
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fs%29%5C*%7B3%2C%7D%28.*%3F%29%28%3F%3D%5C*%7B3%2C%7D%7C%24%29&i=*******%0D%0A%0D%0AThanks%20for%20contacting%20us%0D%0A%0D%0ARegards%2C%0D%0A%0D%0AXXX%0D%0A%0D%0A************%0D%0A%0D%0AIt%20wAS%20a%20pleasure%20talking%20with%20you%0D%0A%0D%0AGood%20to%20see%20you%20today%0D%0A%0D%0A*******)

**Details**

- `(?s)` - `RegexOptions.Singleline` inline modifier
- `\*{3,}` - 3 or more asterisks
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars, as few as possible as `*?` is a lazy quantifier
- `(?=\*{3,}|$)` - a positive lookahead (required to obtain overlapping matches) that matches a location that is followed with 3 or more asterisks or the end of string.

The `.Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value.Trim())` part grabs the value inside Group 1 and trims off leading/trailing whitespace.

Another way is to match the `***`+ line, then capture all lines not stasrting with 3 or more asterisks into Group 1:

```
(?m)^\*{3,}.*((?:\r?\n(?!\*{3,}).*)*)
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%5E%5C*%7B3%2C%7D.*%28%28%3F%3A%5Cr%3F%5Cn%28%3F!%5C*%7B3%2C%7D%29.*%29*%29&i=*******%0D%0A%0D%0AThanks%20for%20contacting%20us%0D%0A%0D%0ARegards%2C%0D%0A%0D%0AXXX%0D%0A%0D%0A************%0D%0A%0D%0AIt%20wAS%20a%20pleasure%20talking%20with%20you%0D%0A%0D%0AGood%20to%20see%20you%20today%0D%0A%0D%0A*******) (it can be used in the above code as is, too.)

**Details**

- `(?m)` - a `RegexOptions.Multiline` modifier to make `^` and `$` match start/end of a line
- `^` - start of line
- `\*{3,}` - 3 or more asterisks
- `.*` - the rest of the line (or use `\r?$` to make sure the end of a line is reached)
- `((?:\r?\n(?!\*{3,}).*)*)` - Group 1: zero or more sequences of

  - `\r?\n(?!\*{3,})` - CRLF or LF line ending that is not followed with 3 or more `*`s
  - `.*` - rest of the string